# Tweepy search not yielding same results as twitter.com search

Tags: twitter, tweepy

Using Tweepy search for instance:

```
for match in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=('from:realdonaldtrump michaelcohen212'), include_entities=True, count=10, wait_on_rate_limit=True).items():
    print(match.text)
```

yields no results but when i search here i get results (although they are from 2015):

```
https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=from%3Arealdonaldtrump%20michaelcohen212&src=typd
```

I tried to filter using Tweepy search operators like `since` and `until` for that specific range and it still yields nothing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of a restriction from Search API.

"The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days."

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/basic-search